# GLControl layout offset wrong on MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, winforms, mono, opentk

I am working on a `OpenGL` application with C# Windows Forms on Windows, Mac and Linux. I use `OpenTK` library with the `GLControl` component to render OpenGL.

It works great on Windows and Linux but on my Mac Mini the `opengl-control` render it wrong, the display has offset problems.

Here I have an example application from OpenTK example Project. The problem is the same there as well:
[image]

As you can see. The actual position should be on the first Arrow. But it render it some pixel down. It seems that when I set the y position at 40px it render it at 40 + 40 * 2 all the time. Only on Y axis.

But when I have it on a `SplitContainer`, it render the whole GLControl on position at 0px, 0px on the window.

Is there anyone who has the same problem with this on MacOS? Is there anyone who has an explanation about this?